# Do we allow "where can I download X" questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, asking-questions

[A user recently asked where they could download the Havok Physics engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135497/where-can-i-get-the-havok-physics-engine-download). I was under the impression that "where can I download X?" questions were considered off-topic, and flagged it as such.

However, since then, two answers have appeared. One of them is by one of our moderators. Are "where can I download X?" questions off-topic? Alternatively, should they be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions asking us for a download source shpuld be considered off-topic, but on a case-by-case analysis, they may still be fairly salveageable.

---

Regardless of policy, I see some issues with these sort of questions.

### The user is asking for a web link

If we assume the download is accessible, it seems to me like good answers would follow the following format:

> You can download X from the (X/Company Y) website. Just follow [this link](http://www.google.com) for the download page.

It seems as if it would be rather difficult to post a *good* answer, *with out* providing the link. This creates a Catch-22; it *can not* be considered a good answer if it does not hold *with out* the link. We have a very strict policy with this, to prevent good answers becoming bad answers due to link rot.

### To a minor extent, the user is asking for *recommendation*

We consider *software and technology recommendation* questions off-topic. I would only *loosely* group these questions in with "where can I download X?", but ultimately, the user is asking us to recommend a specific website to provide the appropriate technology.

One might argue that different answers may also lead to different 'preferred versions'. While this *is* an issue I can see, I am not sure it is really a big one.

---

## Salvage versus Close

It is entirely possible that we could *edit* these questions to be on-topic, and still draw the response the user is looking for.

### Why is X no longer accessible?

Sometimes, the root of the question comes from confusion, when a previously accessible piece of software becomes impossible to find.

In the example, the user likely<sup>1</sup> googled "Havok" and found that although there is a lot of reference to a *shareware* version, there are no links on the official page.

As answers have since pointed out, a semi-recent acquisition resulted in the shareware version being discontinued. Bummer.

I see no reason we can not allow "Why can't I access X anymore?" questions, in the rare situation where this is the actual case. I actually found the answers, in this case, *very helpful*.

### Is X available to the public?

When it comes down to a *complete* lack of being able to find reference to a download, I see no reason why the user can not ask if there *is* a download.

This might highlight the actual problem, as there was with the example question. A good answer would *still* provide links to the download, if valid, while still directly answering the question in *text* format. Win, win.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Assuming, in good faith, that the user did try to find the download, themselves, before posting.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

No, we shouldn't permit "where do I download X" questions. But if it's possible to edit those questions to turn them into something other than a simple link request, we should try to salvage them that way.